# How can I know if the omxplayer is playing or not?

Tags: python, process, raspberry-pi, raspbian, omxplayer

new to programming, I would like to know if there is any way to know if a video is running or not with omxplayer, preferably by returning a boolean, in recent Raspian versions.

If there isn't, how can I get something that does?

The command I'm using to open omxplayer:

```
omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', wakeup])
```

Comment: You can just check if the `omxplayer` is running or not, why are you doing this, maybe there is another option to check that.

Comment: What do you mean? Does it return a boolean if I run just `omxplayer` ?

Comment: I mean if a video is currently being played on Pi you cannot detect that. The only thing you can do is to check whether the `omxplayer` is currently opening or not and based on that concluded a video is being played. `omxplayer` is a player app and when you run it it doesn't return anything.